# ASIHTTP Request failed in log, but requestFailed not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, networking, asihttprequest

I have

```
-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Request Failed Error: %@", error);
}
```

When I make my request I do

```
    //add data to the array
    NSString *json = [array JSONRepresentation];
[request appendPostData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

I'm getting this in my log:

```
 0-08-11 16:52:11.652 MyProject[11720:207] Starting asynchronous request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x5a7df10>
```

2010-08-11 16:52:11.861 MyProject[11720:207] Request  finished downloading data
2010-08-11 16:52:11.861 MyProject[11720:207] Request failed: 
(gdb)

But my log statement in

```
 -(void)requestFailed
```

is not getting called. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Tested in HTTPRequest, looks like the server's returning zero-size data. Probably the problem here, surprised the requestFailed isn't getting called. I guess that's only if the server returns an "I can't do that / your request didn't work" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-requestFailed: is only returned when a request can't be completed - eg. failure to contact the server, or the server didn't conform to the http protocol.

If request can be completed, requestFinished will be called, and you can then check the http status code there, which may indicate a failure. responseStatusText may give more information as to what the failure was.

Comment: Thanks - forgot to set the name of the object I was sending, instead only sending the list of parameters for that object.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the request's `delegate` and `didFailSelector` properties? Usually:

```
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
```

suffices if the `-requestFailed:` method is in the same class implementation file.

Also set the `didFinishSelector` property to call a local selector when then request finishes correctly.

Comment: -requestFailed: is the default failure selectors, so it shouldn't be necessary to set this (though equally it does no harm). Spot on with the setDelegate though, seems the most likely cause.

Comment: Thanks - I did set these, I forgot to include the name of the object when I sent the message, instead sending only a dictionary list.